# Integrate $x^ {1/2}e^{-x}$ using integration by parts

Tags: integration

How to integrate $x^{1/2}e^{-x}$ using integration by parts?

Answer should be $\left(-\sqrt{x} e^{-x}+(1/2)\sqrt{\pi} \mbox{erf}(\sqrt{x})\right)+c$

Comment: You can figure out what u and v were chosen from the first term of the answer, since you know what that is.  That should get you closer.

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with using **e.r.f** but i shall tell you the procedure. Take $u= \sqrt{x}$ and $dv = e^{-x}$. So you have $du = \frac{1}{2 \cdot \sqrt{x}} \ \rm{dx}$ and $v = -e^{-x}$. Now using the integration formula we have,

\begin{align*}
 \int \sqrt{x} e^{-x} \ \textrm{dx} &= \Bigl[ u \cdot v ] - \int v \cdot \ \textrm{du} \\ & = \Bigl [ -\sqrt{x} \cdot e^{-x}\Bigr] + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} \ \textrm{dx}
\end{align*}

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function

Comment: I just wanted to point out what $\operatorname{erf}$ means and that it is common.

Comment: @Theo: Ok. Theo no problem.

Comment: If you have following \begin{align*}
 \int \sqrt{x} e^{-x} \ \textrm{dx} &= \Bigl[ u \cdot v ] - \int v \cdot \ \textrm{du} \\\ & = \Bigl [ -\sqrt{x} \cdot e^{-x}\Bigr] + \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}} \ \textrm{dx}
\end{align*} How you get erf(\sqrt(x)) from there without substitutions

Answer (score 1):

In the comment:

> How you get erf(\sqrt(x)) from there without substitutions

If you leave the $1/2$ in the integral and do the most obvious substitution (recall your first step?), you will get something that should look like the definition of the function in @t.b.'s link.