# Integral of Function related to Error Function (e.r.f)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, error-function

Need help solving this question - I've tried solving it multiple times but to no avail:
$$
I=\int_0^\infty e^{-y^3}.\sqrt y~dy
$$
My approach has been to substitute:
$$
y^3=t\Rightarrow 3.y^2~dy = dt \Rightarrow I= \frac13\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{-1/2}~dt
$$
I'm lost on solving the above Integral. A similar problem suggested the answer in terms of e.r.f. 
[Related Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23224/integrate-x-1-2e-x-using-integration-by-parts) 
However, I'm unable to understand how to solve this integral and get a numerical answer such as $\frac{\sqrt\pi}3 $. (Also, I'm curious as to how did $\pi$ appear in the expression? - My understanding of error functions is very limited. Wikipedia doesn't offer much help in explaining it either).

Comment: Have you heard about [the Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) or the [gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)?

Comment: No, I haven't used it before. I'll check.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. The [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) is given by
$$
\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}~dt, \quad s>0.
$$ Can you apply it here? Do you see the corresponding value for $s$?

Comment: Yes, $ s = \frac 12 $ will apply here. I'll solve it through now

Comment: It's mind-blowing to know $ -{\frac12}!$ becomes $\sqrt\pi$. I now understand why it was a particularly tough problem to solve

Comment: @Abhin33t_S I think you mean $\frac12 !=\sqrt{\pi}$, sure this is not trivial...

Answer (score 1):

Try setting $u=y^{\frac{3}{2}}$. Your integral reduces to 
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-y^3}\sqrt{y}dy=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\frac{1}{3}\sqrt{\pi}
$$